# App freezes everytime I try to resume it after minimize

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-multidex

I recently added Google Analytics 9.0.0. While doing so, I also had to add multidex and

```
dexOptions {  
 javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

to avoid errors. The app seemed to be working fine, but realized that when I pause or minimize the app and resume it again, then the app doenot respond. The screen appears black for few minutes before showing the "app is not responding" message. What should i do?

This is my gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xxxxxxxx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0.3"
    multiDexEnabled true

}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }


}






dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':volley')




compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'me.alexrs:wave-drawable:1.0.0@aar'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.5.1@aar'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

Comment: It is _ANR_ . Are you doing any heavy work in _onResume()_ method?

Comment: In one of the activities I run the google location during onResume(). However, the app was working fine until I introduced dexOptions{javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

Comment: If possible, try removing "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'" and including only the specific play-services that are needed (in addition to the four specific ones, as necessary).  This might reduce the method count below the threshold for multi-dex.

Comment: @TiemSong Yup! Removed "compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0", and just added specific play-services. That worked !! Thanks mate, you saved my day. :) God bless you!

Comment: @mrnobody good to hear!  Cheers.